# PostgreSQL: roles can only access tables they've created

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql (v10) database.  I've created database `tn_beta_db` with schema `tn_schema`.  I've created three users and executed the following, which is meant to grant all of them read and maybe modify access on all tables, current and future that `tn_beta_migrator` might create.

```
\c tn_beta_db

-- User tn_beta_reader --
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA tn_schema FOR ROLE tn_beta_reader GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO tn_beta_reader;

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE tn_beta_db TO tn_beta_reader;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA tn_schema TO tn_beta_reader;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA tn_schema TO tn_beta_reader;


-- User tn_beta_migrator --
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA tn_schema FOR ROLE tn_beta_migrator GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO tn_beta_migrator;

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE tn_beta_db TO tn_beta_migrator;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA tn_schema TO tn_beta_migrator;

GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA tn_schema TO tn_beta_migrator;

GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA tn_schema TO tn_beta_migrator;

-- User tn_beta_writer --
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA tn_schema FOR ROLE tn_beta_writer GRANT SELECT,INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE ON TABLES TO tn_beta_writer;

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE tn_beta_db TO tn_beta_writer;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA tn_schema TO tn_beta_writer;

GRANT SELECT,INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA tn_schema TO tn_beta_writer;
```

If I now connect as `tn_beta_migrator`, I can create a table and do things with it.

```
create table tn_schema.foo(x int);
-- and then INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, even DROP
```

But now if I connect as either of `tn_beta_reader` or `tn_beta_writer`, I can not use that table.

```
tn_beta_db=> select * from tn_schema.foo ;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation foo
tn_beta_db=>
```

I would expect to be able to read/write/modify/delete as `tn_beta_writer` and to be able to read as `tn_beta_reader`.

If I rerun the grant script, above, this permits me to access foo, but a newly created table bar would then be inaccessible.

I'd thought that the `alter default privileges` commands would permit these roles, in the future, to access the tables created by `tn_beta_migrator`.

Any pointers on what I've misunderstood?

Comment: I think the answer here does a really great job of explaining this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/117661.

Specifically, "Default privileges only apply for newly created objects and only for the particular role they are created with". I think this is the relevant part. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role in the `FOR ROLE` clause in `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` is **not** the role that will get the privileges, it is the role that creates the tables.

So your statements should start with

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE tn_beta_migrator ...
```